# "Orthogonal complement" of a closed ball in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, field-theory, characters, locally-compact-groups

Let $t:\mathbb C\to\mathbb R$ be the usual field trace map, then we have the following additive character for the locally compact group $(\mathbb C,+)$.
$$\psi:\mathbb C\to S^1\cong \mathbb C^\ast$$
$$x\mapsto e^{2\pi i\,t(x)}$$

This is called the *standard character of $\mathbb C$* because any other character can be obtained from it by the composition  with the  multiplication map in $\mathbb C$. In other words we have the correspondence
$$\mathbb C\to\widehat{\mathbb C}$$
$$a\mapsto\psi(a\cdot) $$
which is also a topological isomorphism if we endow $\widehat{\mathbb C}$ with the adequate  topology.

---

**Definition:**
Let $G$ be a locally compact group abelian  and let $S$ be a subset. The orthogonal complement (or annihilator) of $S$ is defined as:
$$S^\perp:=\{\chi\in\widehat G\colon \chi(S)=1\}$$

---

In our case, if $S\subset\mathbb C$, then $S^\perp$ can be viewed as a subset of $\mathbb C$ thanks to the above correspondence.

> **Question**:
>   If $S=\{z\in\mathbb C\colon |z|\le c\}$ is the ball of radius $c$ in the complex plane, what is $S^{\perp}\subseteq\mathbb C$?

Comment: It looks like $H$ and $S$ should be the same thing in your definition.

Comment: Yes, sorry I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you could replace $\mathbb{C}$ by $\mathbb{R}^2$, which I'm more comfortable with.  We have the correspondence $x\in\mathbb{R}^2 \leftrightarrow \psi: \xi\mapsto e^{2\pi i \xi\cdot x}$.

Suppose $\xi\mapsto e^{2\pi i \xi\cdot x}$ is in the annihilator.  Then $e^{2\pi i\xi\cdot x}=1$ for all $|\xi| \leq c$.  Take $\xi_0$ in this ball, then $(\xi_0\cdot x) /n$ is an integer for infinitely many $n$, so $x$ must be 0.  That is, the annihilator must be trivial.